# Display group data along with their last latest message

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display result having data categorized in the group with their latest message according to date.
[image]

I tried grouping and having along with nested queries but no luck.

```
SELECT groupName,date FROM chat where groupName  like '%he%' group by groupName,date having min(date);
```

I want the two rows to be printed along having the latest message with them.Here it would be row 4 and row 5. this is just an arbitrary data though which I  need to impplement on bulk.

Comment: For next time, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `group by`, just filtering:

```
select c.*
from chat c
where c.date = (select max(c2.date) from chat c2 where c2.groupname = c.groupname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM chat c 
WHERE 
  groupName  LIKE '%he%'
  AND 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM chat 
    WHERE groupname = c.groupname AND date > c.date
  )
```